# Retrieve rows from data frame for partial matching in column of the data frame with elements in list

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

```
df:  
    chr          gene_name

    1           ARF3
    1           ABC
    1           ARF3,ENSG123
    1           ENSG1245,ARF3, ENSG89
    1           ENSG,ARF3
    1           ANG
    2           XVY
    2           PQR
    3           RST
    4           TAC
```

and a `gene_list`

```
gene_list = ['ARF3','ABC' ]
```

Now, I need to get the rows from the data frame (df) for which the the gene name is either an exact match with elements in gene_list .

So, I tried :

```
df2 = df1[df.gene_name.isin(gene_list)]
```

I retrieved: 
        chr          gene_name

```
    1           ARF3
    1           ABC
```

but what I am expecting is: 
        chr          gene_name

```
     1           ARF3
     1           ABC
     1           ARF3, ENSG123
     1           ENSG1245,ARF3, ENSG89
     1           ENSG,ARF3
     1           ABC
```

so basically all the rows in the data frame where the element in gene_list is a substring of gene_name in the data frame.

I thought of using `".contains()"` had it been I was looking the other way that is `gene_name` in the data frame would have been a substring on element in `gene_list`.

All the help appreciated

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. Although a further query if I may ask you, how do I append the matching gene name in the data frame column as a separate column. So as to retrieve the final output as follows:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simplier solution with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
gene_list = ['ARF3', 'ABC']

df1 = df.gene_name.str.split(',', expand=True)
mask = df1.isin(gene_list)
s = df1[mask].dropna(how='all').apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
s.name='new'

print (s)
0    ARF3
1     ABC
2    ARF3
3    ARF3
4    ARF3
Name: new, dtype: object

print (df.join(s).dropna(subset=['new']))
   chr             gene_name   new
0    1                  ARF3  ARF3
1    1                   ABC   ABC
2    1          ARF3,ENSG123  ARF3
3    1  ENSG1245,ARF3,ENSG89  ARF3
4    1             ENSG,ARF3  ARF3
```

Another solution:

```
gene_list = ['ARF3', 'ABC']

#new dafarame with splited values
df1 = df.gene_name.str.split(',', expand=True)
#mask - True where is desired value
mask = df1.isin(gene_list)
#find first valid value in dataframe and create serie by these values
s = df1[mask].dropna(how='all').apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
s.name='new'
print (s)
0    ARF3
1     ABC
2    ARF3
3    ARF3
4    ARF3
Name: new, dtype: object

#join series to filtered dataframe - create new column
print (df[mask.any(1)].join(s))
   chr             gene_name   new
0    1                  ARF3  ARF3
1    1                   ABC   ABC
2    1          ARF3,ENSG123  ARF3
3    1  ENSG1245,ARF3,ENSG89  ARF3
4    1             ENSG,ARF3  ARF3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is really very helpful.

Comment: Glad I can help you! Good luck!

Comment: In Slovakia is 2:00. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'ARF3'],
                   [1, 'ABC'],
                   [1, 'ARF3,ENSG123'],
                   [1, 'ENSG1245,ARF3,ENSG89'],
                   [1, 'ENSG,ARF3'],
                   [1, 'ANG'],
                   [2, 'XVY'],
                   [2, 'PQR'],
                   [3, 'RST'],
                   [4, 'TAC']], columns=['chr', 'gene_name'])

gene_list = ['ARF3', 'ABC']

df.loc[df.gene_name.str.split(',', expand=True).isin(gene_list).any(1)]

   chr             gene_name
0    1                  ARF3
1    1                   ABC
2    1          ARF3,ENSG123
3    1  ENSG1245,ARF3,ENSG89
4    1             ENSG,ARF3
```

#### Explanation

- `str.split(',', expand=True)` splits by comma, create new DataFrame
- `isin(gene_list)` I hope this one is obvious
- `any(1)` tells me whether any of the values in the series above were in the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This works. Although I have a further query, A small question though, how do I append the matching gene name from a series in another as a separate column .

Comment: I'm working on it!  You should post this as a different question.  If this answered the question above, mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. Although I have a further query to ask you, how do I append the matching gene name in the data frame column as a separate column(Appended_column). So as to retrieve the following column appended   in addition to the above output :                   Appended_column
ARF3                                                                                                         ABC                                    
ARF3
ARF3                                                                                                               ARF3

Comment: @piRSquared, I just did!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1[df1['gene_name'].str.contains(gene)] for gene in gene_list])
```

Let me know if you have more problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But, I get the following error:" AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains' ".                                               Also, how can I append the matching elements in the gene_list as a separate column to the retrieved data frame  so that